# String.Replace() doesn't work with "|"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, replace, filepath

in my current project I want to set a connectionString dynamically.
I get the string with a placeholder (`"|DataDirectory|"`) from my default settings and then I want to replace that placeholder with an actual path.

My Code:

```
connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.KDatabaseConnectionString;
connectionString.Replace(@"|DataDirectory|", Application.StartupPath);
```

I can't get it to work, it doesn't do anything. When I run the code in dubug mode I can see that the connection string contains "`|DataDirectory|`" but it doesn't replace it.

I've seen many questions here about `string.replace()` not working but none of them about my problem. So anyone an idea?

EDIT: ok got it, thanks. Such a bad newbie mistake.

Comment: well, you are replacing the string, but not assigning it, the replace doesn't work on the immutable string itself, you need to assign it back to the connectionString

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't putting the result back into `connectionString`

Try

```
connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.KDatabaseConnectionString;
connectionString = connectionString.Replace(@"|DataDirectory|", Application.StartupPath);
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't code for about half a year and now i'm starting to make such bad mistakes...

Comment: Do not mind. I think most of us have at least experienced or even made similar mistakes more than once in their careers ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the returned value of a `Pure Method`.

In other words, the `.Replace()` method doesn't actually do anything to the variable itself, merely returns the new value for you to use.

The statement that you require is:

`connectionString = connectionString.Replace(@"|DataDirectory|", Application.StartupPath);`

Otherwise you're doing the equivalent of:

```
public string Replace(string str)
{
        Do something...
        return str;
}
```

Where str is passed by `Value` not by `Reference` and then not using the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

```
connectionString = connectionString.Replace(@"|DataDirectory|", Application.StartupPath);
```

Comment: Please provide some more information why this answer solves the problem